# multimap only showing two first elements

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

I'm trying to iterate over every element in my multimap but for some reason it stops working after it goes over the first two elements.

This is the code that I'm using to iterate:

```
    for(noteIT = trackIT->noteList.begin(); noteIT != trackIT->noteList.end(); noteIT++){
        cout << "noteList size is: " << (int) trackIT->noteList.size() << endl;
        cout << "---" << noteIT->second.getName() << endl;
    }
```

This is the output that I get:

```
noteList size is: 3
---note1
noteList size is: 3
---note2
```

But there's more than two elements inside my multimap, I'm adding them here:

```
// create notes
Note note1(440, 100, 8, 1, 1);
note1.setName("note1");
Note note2(220, 100, 8, 1, 9);
note2.setName("note2");
Note note3(880, 100, 8, 1, 17);
note3.setName("note3");

synthTrack.addNote(note1);
synthTrack.addNote(note2);
synthTrack.addNote(note3);
```

This is what the addNote method looks like:

```
void Track::addNote(Note &note) {
//  long key = note.getMeasureNumber() * 1000000 + note.getStartTime();
    long key = 1000009;
    this->noteList.insert(make_pair(key, note));
}
```

A multimap can have the same key several times so right now every key is equal but that shouldn't matter. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

[Here's a running example](http://codepad.org/IVQ2d5G5). Sadly, this example works as it should and shows the three notes that are added to the noteList. The code above however, does not work and I have no idea why.

Comment: We'd have a better chance if you posted a minimal complete example.

Comment: In particular, it would be good to see the multimap template parameters, and `operator<` function you defined for `Note`....

Comment: There is no `operator<` function because I don't need the multimap to be ordered. I'll add a working example

Comment: Here's a working example. Sadly, the simplified example does work, but the code inside the rest of my project stops after two Note objects are shown with cout... I have no idea what could be causing this

Comment: This is progress! Try a middle case, simplified about half as much. Soon we'll have the bug cornered.

Comment: I also tried with the trackIT loop added and still everything is working fine. There's not much else missing and I really can't figure out what could be the problem atm

Comment: I suggest you run it in a debugger, and go through the loop step by step checking all variables and conditions.

Comment: "The code above" looks *exactly* like the "running example". What is the "not much else" that's different? Stop being coy, put the error-producing code on codepad too, and we can solve this thing.

Comment: Here's a complete example: http://codepad.org/mPeWImht
On my local machine this is running just fine though (so I still can't figure the problem from thos) but on codepad it's giving errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the codepad example, your problem lies in the way you're calling `getTracklist()` within the `for` loop.

Each time you call `getTracklist()`, it returns a *copy* of `tracklist`.  So by doing `trackIT < playlist.getTracklist().end()` inside the `for` loop, you're comparing an iterator from one copy of `tracklist` with an iterator to a different copy of `tracklist`.

You safe way out of this is to copy `tracklist` to a local variable before the `for` loop and use that:

```
vector<Track> tracklist(playlist.getTracklist());
for(trackIT = tracklist.begin(); trackIT != tracklist.end(); ++trackIT){
```

An alternative is to leave your `for` loop as is, but change your getter for `tracklist` to:

```
vector<Track>& getTracklist() { return tracklist; }
```

By returning a reference to `tracklist`, you will be comparing iterators to same actual object.  However, this way is a good bit more risky and should probably only be used as a last resort.

As an aside, it's not normally a good plan to compare iterators using `<`, prefer `!=`.  This works here because the container is a `std::vector`, but if you change to a different container type in the future, this could cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: I had just figured out the problem was with the getter but thanks for explaining why it was breaking the code.